# What's the use of vmem? Can I use vmem in python?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, memory

In my cluster, I can use only 20 Gb mem, and 230 Gb vmem. And I write a python script to call a execution file (using `subprocess`). Each call (the `func`) spends around 0.5 Gb memory. And I use `multiprocess` for multi call in the same time. A brief code as a illustration is:

```
import pathos.multiprocessing as mp

def func(i):
    subprocess.call(['cp',exe_file, exe_file+str(i)])
    p = subprocess.Popen(['./'+exe_file+str(i)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    err = p.communicate()[1]
    p.wait()

def fun_parallel(N):
    p=mp.Pool(N)
    p.map(func,range(100))
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

the `exe_file` is the execution file and `N` is the number of `func` running in the same time. ( I have many threads, so I can set `N` equal to 16, 32, 64, .... needn't consider the limit of threads )

My question is very simple,

1. When I set N=32, it works well, when I set N=64, it breaks

`OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory`

I guess the reason is that for N=32, the memory used is 32*0.5=16Gb and for N=64, the memory used is 64*0.5=32Gb which is above the mem limit 20 Gb.

So what's the use of of vmem? Since I have 230 Gb vmem, can it do anything?

2. Can I avoid this problem in python code, for example when the memory is almost done, stop calling `func`? ( but I don't think it's a good way...) Is there any good way to use the every potential of cluster automatically?

Comment: Virtual memory isn't real memory. Running subprocesses requires real memory.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks, and is there any way to use vmem? Should I use os.system ? Will using vmem decrease the speed significantly?